# JMeter plugins in Visual Studio Online

Tags: jmeter, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Is there any way to install JMeter plugins in VSO?

I want to test with JMeter an application that requires AzureAD authentication. I couldn't find any other way to authenticate than programmatically (could it be possible to simulate requests). But this requires installing JMeter plugins in VSO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just provide the necessary jar(s) using `Supporting files` input (like you do for any CSV files user for parameterisation or *jmeter.properties* overrides)

[image: JMeter Plugins Visual Studio Online]

Actually I don't think you will be able to find the relevant plugin, I would rather recommend using [Java Azure AD Authentication library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java) from [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), it seems to be the easiest solution.

See [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for more information